# How to use words like Cusp and Nadir,

Tags: phrases

1st Q: How do I construct any sentences referring to man's personal well-being with the word nadir.

&

2nd Q: How do I describe humans touch or feelings using the word CUSP.

Comment: The question is Not Constructive. If you have something to say about the human condition where it's appropriate to use these words then do. But I suspect you just like the words (for unfathomable reasons) and are inviting people to construct inspiring quotes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Both terms have an astrological/mathematical origin, but if you choose to use them colloquially, the meanings are figurative.

For example, if the man's personal well-being has taken a turn for the worse and he's been on a trajectory downward — if he's at the point where things can get no worse, you can say he's hit rock bottom. You can also say he's reached the *nadir* of well-being.

A figurative meaning of *cusp* is used to suggest something simultaneously in transition — while about to enter an imminent new phase or state. If you describe a person's feelings as being "on the cusp," you'll need to establish where they are coming from, and the state into which they will next be. "I'm on the cusp of loving you" would suggest the person isn't quite there yet -- but that's the direction of affection.